# "Desenvolver" o produto neste contexto significa melhorá-lo, produzí-lo ou adicionar uma matéria a ele?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Contexto:

> DAILY SHAMPOO – Linha NT Daily Care Professional.Shampoo de uso diário que promove uma limpeza suave dos fios, da raiz às pontas, deixando-os extremamente macios e sedosos. **Desenvolvido**, principalmente, com queratina, aminoácidos e extrato de algas marinhas que equilibram a oleosidade dos mesmos, protegem e conferem brilho intenso.

O que significa *"desenvolvido"* aqui? Que o shampoo foi "melhorado" com a queratina, os aminoácidos etc, que foi "produzido" usando essas matérias ou que essas matérias foram adicionadas a ele?

Preciso saber por uma tradução que estou fazendo.

Comment: Mesmo procurando a definição de **Desenvolvido** no dicionário e não achando referência a fabricado ou criado,  acredito que tenha esse sentido.

Answer (score 2):

**Desenvolvido** tem como sinônimo, **Produzido**. Acredito que é esse o sentido da palavra **Desenvolvido** nessa frase.

> Sinônimo de desenvolvido Compartilhar 52 sinônimos de desenvolvido
>   para 5 sentidos da palavra desenvolvido:
>
> **Que está avançado:**
>
> 1 avançado, adiantado, antecipado, progressista, próspero,
>   florescente, moderno, civilizado, rico.
>
> **Que está crescido:**
>
> 2 crescido, grande, alto, forte, robusto, corpulento, musculoso,
>   musculado, volumoso, vigoroso, resistente, poderoso.
>
> **Que foi ampliado:**
>
> 3 ampliado, aumentado, expandido, extenso, amplo, largo, estendido,
>   dilatado, desdobrado, acrescentado.
>
> **Que foi criado:**
>
> 4 criado, concebido, feito, elaborado, preparado, produzido, composto,
>   confeccionado.
>
> **Que foi aprofundado:**
>
> 5 aprofundado, aperfeiçoado, otimizado, incrementado, esquadrinhado,
>   perscrutado, examinado, investigado, pesquisado, estudado, explicado,
>   exposto, explanado.

Fonte: [sinônimos.com.br](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/desenvolvido/)

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta e sua opinhão. Saudações.

Answer (score 2):

[**Desenvolvido**](http://www.aulete.com.br/desenvolvido) pode significar **criado**, **elaborado** ou **aperfeiçoado** (melhorado, aprimorado, etc).

No caso específico do texto:

> Desenvolvido, principalmente, com queratina, aminoácidos e extrato de algas marinhas...

O texto pode dar a entender que houve muito trabalho, estudo e/ou pesquisa para produzir o shampoo com os ingredientes citados. Apesar de existirem muitos shampoos com queratina, por exemplo, a palavra **desenvolvido** pode ter sido escolhida por passar uma impressão que o processo de criação do produto foi mais cuidadoso, criterioso, moderno, etc - e isso seria um diferencial (mesmo usando um ingrediente comum a produtos concorrentes).

Se o texto fosse escrito como *"Feito/produzido/fabricado com queratina..."*, daria a impressão de que os ingredientes simplesmente estão lá, foram misturados de maneira "convencional", e o produto é "comum", sem nenhum diferencial.

Mas ao usar *"desenvolvido com..."*, passa-se a ideia de que o processo de criação foi mais criterioso e que o produto final é melhor (afinal, **desenvolver** também [significa **progredir**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/desenvolver), no sentido de *melhorar*).

No fim, acaba significando as duas coisas: o produto não só foi produzido com os ingredientes citados, como também foi melhorado (mesmo que o concorrente use os mesmos ingredientes, este é melhor, etc).

Comment: Obrigada pela explicação e tudo. Sua resposta ficou muito útil. Saudações.